# Actors case class simple example

Tags: scala, actor

I'm almost certainly doing something profoundly stupid which makes this actor not work properly, but I can't see it after a chunk of time staring at it. So I thought I'd ask SO.

I can't get this code to work - in that, if I send it messages such as 4 (which should trigger the default case), nothing is printed, and I can't trip the monitor by sending it a temperature alarm.

What am I doing wrong?

```
class TemperatureMonitor extends Actor {
  var tripped : Boolean = false
  var tripTemp : Double = 0.0

  def act() {
    while (true) {
      receive {
        case Heartbeat => 0
        case TemperatureAlarm(temp) =>
          tripped = true
          tripTemp = temp
        case _ => println("No match")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what about the code that creates the actor, starts it and sends it a message?

Comment: why: "while(true)" and not "loop"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you don't show how you create the actor we can only guess. The first thing I would check is that you've started the actor:

```
val monitor = new TemperatureMonitor
monitor.start
monitor ! 4 // should trigger the default case, as you say
```

Comment: Indeed. When I came back to this fresh, it seemed to run correctly without any fuss. No idea what was wrong, maybe just explaining it to SO fixed it in my head.